# React Native Post Request via Fetch throws Network Request Failed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch-api

I've came across the following error.
At the moment I developing an Android App with React Native therefore I'm planning to use fetch for doing a post request for me.

```
fetch("https://XXreachable-domainXX.de/api/test", {
    method: "post",

    body: JSON.stringify({
      param: 'param',
      param1: 'param',

    })
  })
  .then((response) = > response.json())
  .then((responseData) = > {
    ToastAndroid.show(
      "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData.message), ToastAndroid.SHORT
    )
  })
  .catch((error) = > {
    console.warn(error);
  });
```

The app now throws an error:

> TypeError: Network request failed

When I change the code to a GET-Request it's working fine, in the browser with a window.alert() as a return it's cool and also the Chrome extension Postman returns data correctly.

Comment: Please refer foillowing link:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5222#issuecomment-170239302

Comment: If someone has this problem on iOS, make sure you are using https not just http. The default settings are only to support https.

Comment: How does one change the settings to support HTTP?

Comment: You need to approve domains in `info.plist`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed

Comment: Even if one is not online a red screen saying Network request failed not looks good, is there a way to handle that in own way like a alert or something..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This React Native's error is rather useless, so you need to get the actual underlying error first. The most straightforward way is to write a small native program that would just perform the same query using `HttpsURLConnection`.

For me the actual error was `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`
which has a well known solution: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#MissingCa

This is quite likely your case also, given that the browsers and Postman have no problem with the request. To check it run `openssl s_client -connect XXreachable-domainXX.de:443 -showcerts`. If there are certificate errors, fix them first, it could spare you time writing the native program.

Edit: actually the easiest way to see all underlying android errors for react native is simply running 'adb logcat' in terminal

Answer (score 16):

Developing with Windows OS/PHP built-in server/react-native Android on device:

- check server local IP address (`ipconfig`), e.g. 172.16.0.10
- in react-native `fetch` use this URL and proper port (`fetch('http://172.16.0.10:8000/api/foo)`)
- run PHP built-in server with this specific IP instead of the localhost: `php -S 172.16.0.10:8000 ...`
- turn off Windows firewall for the private networks

That fixed the connection problem between Android phone and the local server for me.

Comment: Just switching out `localhost` for my local IP did the trick, maybe a bug parsing `localhost`?

Answer (score 14):

None of the other answers helped me.
The problem was `headers`:

Old header:

```
fetch(API_HOST, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Updated header:

```
fetch(config.API_HOST, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'  // I added this line
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Comment: Had the same problem. This solved it! Thanks

Comment: Amazing, catch... you have saved my day. Thanks! nice work.

Answer (score 6):

If you have had this error and you are sure everything works well *and* you are running an emulator, simply close your emulator and fire it up again.

It should run now.

This usually happens after you have hibernated your system for a while

Answer (score 3):

step1>
add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" line in AndroidManifest.xml like:

// add this line
...
step2>
Delete all debug folder from your android folder..

Comment: As of API level 28, this defaults to false. If you want to use HTTP (not HTTPS), you need to set this to true. Helped me -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue using the fetch,this is a type error.so try using Axios. This worked for me.

the code which wasnt working :`error:[typeError : network Request failed]`

```js
return fetch(addProduceApi, { method: 'PATCH', body: bodyParamData, headers: getAuthHeader() })
.then((response: any) => response.json()) .catch((error: any) => console.log('Error in patchProduce: ', error));
```

the working code:

```js
return axios.patch(addProduceApi,produceData,{ headers: getAuthHeader()}) 

.then((response: any) => response.json()) .catch((error: any) => console.log('Error in patchProduce: ', error));?
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a major issue doing the same on the android emulator. On iOS approving the domain in the info.plist was necessary. To be clear I was attempting to login to my .NET web hosted API.

The fix was to make sure the post data was parameterised.( I'm pretty sure that's a word)

```
export const loginUser = ({ userName, password }) => {
const data = `UserName=${userName}&Password=${password}&grant_type=password`
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER })

        fetch(URL_LOGIN, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: data
            // body: {

            //     UserName: userName,
            //     Password: password,
            //     grant_type: 'password'

            // }

        })
            .then((response) => { 
                loginUserSuccess(dispatch, response)
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                loginUserFailed(dispatch, response)
            })
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem on emulator make sure you also test it on the device. It's most probably not happening there.

Just so you know there's nothing to worry about if you can work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Android due to an expired certificate. The error message I had was `com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: Certificate expired at Fri Sep 29 16:33:39 EDT 2017 (compared to Fri Dec 08 14:10:58 EST 2017)`.

I was able to confirm this using [digicert.com](https://digicert.com/help).

Unfortunately I did have to dig rather deep into the React Native code and debug the XHR code in the bundle `(index.android.bundle)` in order to find the error message and the URL in question, because it was in some of my logging code, which I obviously didn't log to the console as well. :)

I was helped by [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5222#issuecomment-170239302).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was fixed when I restarted the emulator

Answer (score -5):

Check two cases bellow

1. Wrong end-point
2. Internet connection: both real-device, virtual-device

It has eaten 2 hour with the second reason.

Comment: That should rather be a comment. This is **not** an answer to the question.

Comment: thats not an answer