# React Native fetch() Network Request Failed

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

When I create a brand new project using `react-native init` (RN version 0.29.1) and put a fetch in the render method to the public facebook demo movie API, it throws a `Network Request Failed`. There is a very useless stack trace and I can't debug network requests in the chrome console. Here is the fetch I'm sending:

```
fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.movies;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using the iOS simulator and I thought it used my computer's internet connection

Comment: Try loading the simulator manually and opening the url in safari

Comment: `http` -> `https` (if possible) will most likely fix your issue

Comment: I was using the ip `192.168.1.25:3000` from `ifconfig` without binding my server to that ip `rails server --binging=192.168.1.25 --port=3000`

Comment: None of these answers allow you to catch the error.

Comment: facing same issue. How did you solve?

Comment: @VigneswaranA there are more than 15 upvoted answers to this question. Did you try to apply any of these solutions? Nothing worked for you?

Comment: Yes I tried all.  Nothing worked for me

Comment: @VigneswaranA, this helped me: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/116#issuecomment-405350732

Comment: Hi everyone! it's the end of 2023 and it's so crazy hard to send request in react native

Comment: In case this helps someone: I got this error for an https url. Turns out the protocol had been capitalised to "Https". In my case, lowercasing the protocol solved it. I'm guessing fetch doesn't recognise Https as valid.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The problem here is that iOS does not allow HTTP requests by default, only HTTPS. If you want to enable HTTP requests add this to your `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. For others new to React Native, this file (info.plist) can also be edited through xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38219454/1299792

Comment: its not add but replace. The code is already in the info.plist, you need to replace the section or you will get an error.

Comment: what about android? I am facing same issue in android as well.

Comment: Exactly. Anyone have the answer for android?

Comment: when i put that on ios/build/info.plist and run: 
react-native run-ios

The ios/build/info.plist is overwritten and quit my changes

What should i do ?

Comment: @JorgeWanderSantanaUreña modify [your_project_folder_name]/ios/[your_project_folder_name]/In‌​fo.plist

Comment: For Android give INTERNET permission

Comment: I have given INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifest.xml but yet I am having this issue. Any idea how to fix it? I would have torn all my hairs if I had any..grrr

Comment: @masud_moni have you find any solution?

Comment: I have a partial solution. :( I just can send the request to the server, not my localhost.

Comment: what about `android` ? Im facing this issue right now

Comment: @kurniawan26 have you found any solution?

Comment: @Sujit yup, I solved it. In my case it was Android emulator always sent `charset: utf-8` on the header. so I need to ask my friend (backend) to changed the `nginx` setting to allow that additional header.

Comment: @kurniawan26 For me the issue with Certificate.

Comment: I am using expo to run the application on my iOS device. I made these changes but did not work. Any solutions that work?

Comment: @Sujit How did you fix the issue with Certificate finally?

Answer (score 73):

I was using `localhost` for the address, which was obviously wrong. After replacing it with the IP address of the server (in the network that emulator is), it worked perfectly.

**Edit**

In Android Emulator, the address of the development machine is `10.0.2.2`. More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer)

For Genymotion, the address is `10.0.3.2`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257266/how-to-access-localhost-from-a-genymotion-android-emulator)

Comment: Thank you. Probably the only response I've seen that works for android. Used my networks IP address and it works. eg `http://<Network IP emulator connects to>:<port where API is served>/api/tasks`

Comment: Don't forget the "http://" or else it won't work ... was wondering why it would work on postman but not with fetch

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs Your answer help me a lot of, thank you so much, I am using android emulator.

Comment: Yes this works. Change from localhost to the actual IP address of your development computer.

Answer (score 67):

Not recommended to allow all domains for http.
Make an exception for just the necessary domains.

Source: [Configuring App Transport Security Exceptions in iOS 9 and OSX 10.11](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

Add the following to the info.plist file of your app:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: what about android?

Comment: There seems to be multiple info.plist files in multiple directories in my React Native app. Any idea which folder contains the correct file to change?

Comment: @Marklar [your_project_folder_name]/ios/[your_project_folder_name]/Info.plist

Comment: if I use my localhost here: <key>yourserver.com</key>, when ready I'm ready to publish, I'll need to change it, correct?

Answer (score 41):

I got the same issue on Android 9 because of the "http" and issue resolved by just adding **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** in 
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 .......>
 .......
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well. It happens because Android is not supporting HTTP anymore per default on API 28.

Answer (score 25):

For us it was because we were uploading a file and the RN filePicker did not give the proper mime type. It just gave us 'image' as the type. We needed to change it to 'image/jpg' to get the fetch to work.

```
form.append(uploadFileName, {
  uri : localImage.full,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: uploadFileName
 })
```

Comment: @JohhanSantana You could probably look at the raw image data and get it from the beginning, but the react native picker just came back 'image' for me.

Answer (score 18):

if you using localhost just change it :

from :`http://localhost:3030`
to   :`http://10.0.2.2:3030`

Comment: How do you change it from localhost to your IP address?

Comment: @Olumide just change your url . And thanks this worked

Comment: I changed it from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://192.168.1.256:3000` and it worked

Comment: `http://10.0.2.2:3030` works! But why?

Answer (score 16):

I got the same issue on Android but I managed to find a solution for it. Android is blocking cleartext traffic (non-https-requests) since API Level 28 by default. However, react-native adds a network-security-config to the debug version (`android/app/src/debug/res/xml/react_native_config.xml`) which defines some domains (localhost, and the host IPs for AVD / Genymotion), which can be used without SSL in dev mode. 
You can add your domain there to allow http requests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">dev.local</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: This worked for me with react native 0.59 and target sdk 28 :)

Comment: that would be nice if I even had res/xml/... path... should I add, will it make a difference?
using RN - 0.72 , sdk > 30

Answer (score 15):

**For Android user:**

1. Replace `localhost`s to a Lan IP addresses because when you run the project on an Android device, localhost is pointing to the Android device, instead of your computer, example: change `http://localost` to `http://192.168.1.123`
2. If your request URL is HTTPS and your Android device is under a proxy, assume you have installed User-added CA(like burp suite's CA or Charles's CA) in your Android device, make sure your Android version is below **Nougat(7.0)**, because: [Changes to Trusted Certificate Authorities in Android Nougat](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html)

   > **User-added CAs**
   >   Protection of all application data is a key goal of the
   >   Android application sandbox. Android Nougat changes how applications
   >   interact with user- and admin-supplied CAs. By default, apps that
   >   target API level 24 will—by design—not honor such CAs unless the app
   >   explicitly opts in. This safe-by-default setting reduces application
   >   attack surface and encourages consistent handling of network and
   >   file-based application data.

Answer (score 12):

React Native Docs gives the answer for this.

> Apple has blocked implicit cleartext HTTP resource loading. So we need to add the following our project's Info.plist (or equivalent) file.

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

[React Native Docs -> Integration With Existing Apps -> Test your integration -> Add App Transport Security exception](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#test-your-integration)

Comment: It changed nothing :/

Answer (score 11):

The problem may be in server configuration.

Android 7.0 has a bug [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133437/sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-n-7-0). Workaround proposed by Vicky Chijwani:

> Configure your server to use the elliptic curve prime256v1. For
>   example, in Nginx 1.10 you do this by setting ssl_ecdh_curve
>   prime256v1;

Answer (score 11):

I was having this problem for Android-

URL- localhost/authToken.json - didn't work :(

URL- 10.106.105.103/authToken.json - didn't work :(

URL- http://10.106.105.103/authToken.json - worked :) :D

Note- Use `ifconfig` on Linux or `ipconfig` on Windows to find machine IpAddress

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue on Android Emulator, where I tried to access an external HTTPS URL with a valid certificate. But fetching that URL in react-native failed

```
'fetch error:', { [TypeError: Network request failed]
sourceURL: 'http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' }
```

1) To find out the exact error in the logs, I first enabled 'Debug JS Remotely' using Cmd + M on the app

2) The error reported was

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

3) I added the URL's valid certificate using this method -> STEP 2

```
http://lpains.net/articles/2018/install-root-ca-in-android/
```

This certificate gets added to the User tab.

4) Add the attribute `android:networkSecurityConfig` attribute to AndroidManifest.xml

Add a Network Security Configuration file
`res/xml/network_security_config.xml:`

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

This should work and give you an expected response.

Comment: I just needed to do step 4 in order to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For Android, you may have missed to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml
Need to add the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I already do have that even though I am getting that error, is there any other workaround?

Comment: @masud_moni you find way to fix the problem? im still having the same problem

Comment: @RafaelRotiroti yes i solved that issue, but although it is been a while, it is hard to remember, if you have used the permission and still facing issues, please share details. I will try my best to help, and you will have others also to look into it

Comment: @masud_moni thank you, i've fixed that problem using the ip given after run ifconfig command. AVD creates an virtual device, so using the same theory than virtual machines that is nothing hosted in 127.0.0.1 in my device. So i use 192.168.x.x IP and everything works fine as well

Answer (score 5):

I have similar problem. 
In my case requests to localhost was working and suddenly stopped.
It turn out that the problem was that I was turn off my wifi on my android phone.

Answer (score 4):

in my case i have https url but fetch return Network Request Failed error so i just stringify the body and it s working fun

```js
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue'
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, android uses a special type of IP address 10.0.2.2 then port number

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

export const baseUrl = Platform.OS === 'android' ?
    'http://10.0.2.2:3000/'
: 
'http://localhost:3000/';
```

Comment: Sad that this is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

**By running the mock-server on 0.0.0.0**

 Note: This works on Expo when you are running another server using json-server.

Another approach is to run the mock server on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1.

This makes the mock server accessible on the LAN and because Expo requires the development machine and the mobile running the Expo app to be on the same network the mock server becomes accessible too.

This can be achieved with the following command when using json-server

`json-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 ./db.json --watch`

Visit this [link](https://dsinecos.github.io/blog/How-to-call-a-locally-hosted-server-from-expo-app) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml and then replace fetch URL domain **(localhost)** with your IP address,

```
const dataRaw = await fetch('http://192.168.8.102:4000');
```

Comment: replacing with ip worked.

Answer (score 2):

if you use docker for the REST api, a working case for me was to replace hostname: `http://demo.test/api` with the machine ip address:  `http://x.x.x.x/api` . You can get the IP from checking what ipv4 you have on your wireless network. You should have also the wifi from phone on.

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the error case in .then for fetch API.

For example:

```
fetch(authURl,{ method: 'GET'})
.then((response) => {      
  const statusCode = response.status;
  console.warn('status Code',statusCode);
  if(statusCode==200){
    //success code
  }else{
    //handle other error code
  }      
},(err) => {
  console.warn('error',err)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  return error;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For me ... I have `https` already ... and the issue went away once I added `'Content-type': 'application/json'` to `headers`

```
headers: {
  Authorization: token,
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  /** rest of headers... */
}
```

**Platform:** Android

Answer (score 2):

In my case i just change `https` to `http` and the problem was resolved (Using android studio).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but option.
I switched to https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob
It works good both for form-data and files

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP` is not allowed anymore. Pleas use `HTTPS`

Starting with Android API 28 and iOS 9, these platforms disable insecure HTTP connections by default.

Answer (score 1):

It my case, it was showing same for `https` requests as well.

**Reinstalling the application** solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with React-native Expo and Node Express back-end. The problem is about a conflict between an emulator localhost and server localhost. Your back-end-server might be ruunning on 127.0.0.1:8000, but an emulator can't find this.

In terminal find your Ipv4-Address with a command 'ipconfig'. For ex., it will be 192.138.1.40

After this put it into your fetch ( 'http://192.138.1.40:8080/').
And what is also important - run your back-end-server with the same host and port.
On Node Express for example:

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Server is running!"))

Comment: Thank you. Your answer worked for me with using express as the backend and an expo application on a real android device.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` line in AndroidManifest.xml.
2. Delete all debug folder from your android folder.

Comment: This works but additionally, you should map the requests in the app to the host port through `adb devices` to get list of emulators running on your machine and the mapping out the ports with e.g `adb -s [emulator name] reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000` this makes that all the request in the devices pointing to 3000 are received in the host machine

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple update nodejs version 14 or higher

Comment: why this fixes the issue?

Comment: because invalid connection over tls in my case

Answer (score 0):

`"dependencies": {"react": "17.0.2","react-native": "0.66.1"},`
I faced this problem with the **Android emulator**.

1. Add these lines of code inside AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
    <application
     ....
     ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
   ```
2. Then, try to run your code in a real physical device, instead of emulator, 
   to run on physical devices - connect your usb and try to run npx react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

#### fixed `TypeError: Network request failed` when upload file to http not https with Android debug builds

In react-native 0.63.2 (I'm testing) or some higher version, if just use `fetch` to upload file to a http (not https) server, will meet `TypeError: Network request failed`.

Here I use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)@0.27.2 as client running on an Android phone successfully upload a file to [react-native-file-server](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-file-server) as server running on another Android phone.

client need edit JAVA and JS code, server no need edit JAVA code.

With debug builds, must [commenting out line number 43 in this file android/app/src/debug/java/com/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/ReactNativeFlipper.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551?fbclid=IwAR1dCW_dUokc4l6CNooMLP7E1Na9jz4s2xXvtfqic9MTi-mgTSWLvpHWHXw#issuecomment-611085378)

```
38      NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
39      NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
40          new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
41            @Override
42            public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
43      //        builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
44            }
45          });
46      client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
```

Maybe also need add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` under `<application` of `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` , on my test, it's not necessary on both debug and release builds.

```
  onFileSelected = async (file) => {
    // API ref to the server side BE code `addWebServerFilter("/api/uploadtodir", new WebServerFilter()`
    // https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-file-server/blob/1034a33dd6d8b0999705927ad78368ca1a639add/android/src/main/java/webserver/WebServer.java#L356
    // could not be 'localhost' but IP address
    const serverUploadApi = 'http://192.168.1.123:8080/api/uploadtodir';

    // the folder on server where file will be uploaded to, could be e.g. '/storage/emulated/0/Download'
    const serverFolder = '/storage/emulated/0/FileServerUpload';

    const fileToUpload = {
      // if want to upload and rename, it can be `name: 'foo.bar'`, but can not be 'foo'
      // only if your server upload code support file name without type, on our server
      // https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-file-server/blob/1034a33dd6d8b0999705927ad78368ca1a639add/android/src/main/java/webserver/WebServer.java#L372
      // will cause java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in substring()
      name: file.name,

      // type is necessary in Android, it can be 'image/jpeg' or 'foo/bar', but can not be
      // 'foo', 'foo/', '/foo' or undefined, otherwise will cause `[AxiosError: Network Error]`
      type: 'a/b',

      uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? file.uri : file.uri.replace('file://', ''),
    };

    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('path', serverFolder);
    form.append('uploadfile', fileToUpload);

    // ref to the server side FE code `this.axios.post("/api/uploadtodir", parms, config)`
    // https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-file-server/blob/1034a33dd6d8b0999705927ad78368ca1a639add/fileserverwebdoc/src/views/Manage.vue#L411
    let res = await axios.post(serverUploadApi, form, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        console.warn(progressEvent);
      },
    });

    // ref to the server side BE code `return newFixedLengthResponse("Suss");`
    // https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-file-server/blob/1034a33dd6d8b0999705927ad78368ca1a639add/android/src/main/java/webserver/WebServer.java#L380
    if (res.data === 'Suss') {
      console.warn('Upload Successful');
    } else if (res.data === 'fail') {
      console.warn('Upload Failed');
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to a HTTPS website please check the internet connection of your emulator. (In my case, I'm using a **connected phone emulator via USB** and it's internet was offline)

Answer (score 0):

To find the root problem i used `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch` and after sending a request an exception threw with the message that tells the actual problem `HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED`.

apparently react native (in my case v0.59) fetch only supports http/1.1 then i disabled http/2 on the webserver.

if your webserver is IIS look at this question [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083437/disable-http2-on-windows-server-2016-at-site-level)

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your SSL is properly configured putting the url [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20verify%20the%20SSL,click%20the%20Check%20SSL%20button.).

Answer (score 0):

I also have problem is on the android. my android sdk is 28.

I have try and plan. That all unavailable. And my request url is inclues https. request type is post.

after , i founded add the form-data header , can resolve this problem

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

and the body like this

```
a=a&b=b
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue now resolved :).
I Am using django as backend and react native in expo. Run your Django project on your ipv4 address with python manage.py runserver ipv4address:8080 (you can find your ipv4 address by running ipconfig command in terminal).In react native fetch method use this address.
fetch methord=

```
fetch('http://<your ipv4>:8080/endpoint/', {method: 'POST',headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},body: JSON.stringify(data)})
```

Answer (score 0):

### 2023 version

For expo workflow on native platforms, use `Constants.expoConfig?.hostUri`

If you have a port that you need to use, you can use this snippet:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const YOUR_API_PORT = "1234"

export const developmentUri = `http://${Constants.expoConfig?.hostUri
    ?.split(`:`)
    ?.shift()
    ?.concat(YOUR_API_PORT)}`;
```

For react native with web, you can directly use your `http://localhost:1234`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Expo. I was able to run my app without issues with EAS with the `development` profile, that has `developmentClient: true`, while my `preview` profile that is the same as the `development`, except without `developmentClient` defined, gave errors.

Using the following setting (`app.config.js`) solved the issue:

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "usesCleartextTraffic": true
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

The setting `usesCleartextTraffic` allows requests over HTTP (non secure).

I guess it defaults to `true` when `developmentClient: true`, but I expected that such a behaviour was documented in the docs (https://docs.expo.dev/build/eas-json/), because it took me some time to solve the issue, and the error itself (`Network Request Failed`) was not very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Just you have Changes in Fetch....

```
fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        /*return responseJson.movies; */
        alert("result:"+JSON.stringify(responseJson))
        this.setState({
            dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseJson)
        })
     }).catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
     });
```

Answer (score -1):

For Android devices, go to your project root folder and run the command:

```
adb reverse tcp:[your_own_server_port] tcp:[your_own_server_port]
```

e.g., `adb reverse tcp:8088 tcp:8088`

This will make your physical device(i.e. Android phone) listen to the localhost server running on your development machine (i.e. your computer) on address http://localhost:[your_own_server_port].

After that, you can directly use `http:localhost:[your_port] /your_api` in your react-native `fetch(`) call.

Answer (score -1):

For android, add android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" to application tag in AndroidManifest.xml, like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest ... >
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                        ... >
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

network_security_config.xml file content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<network-security-config>
<debug-overrides>
    <trust-anchors>
        <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
        <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>

<!-- let application to use http request -->
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: could you please elaborate, and explain in details? I am just curious how it works?

Comment: Have modified the comment, hope that will help

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the Android emulator wasn't connected to the Wi-Fi.

See here [Android Studio - Android Emulator Wifi Connected with No Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670547/android-studio-android-emulator-wifi-connected-with-no-internet)