# React Native Changing Variable with State

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react and I just started playing around with state and props. 
What I have been trying is to fetch some data and then populate with it some card views.
This is how my code looks so far:

```
class Two extends React.Component {
constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      day: "Monday",
    };
  }

// Getting monthly schedule
    getSchedules = () => {
        fetch("http://xxxxxx/getschedules.php", {method: "GET"})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            AlertIOS.alert(
                "GET Response",
                "Search Query -> " + responseData.result.length)
                this.setState({day: responseData.result[1].day}); //changing state but nothing changes
        })
        .then((data) => { 
         console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
         console.log(err);
        })
        .done();
    }

  render() {  
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getSchedules}>
              <View style={styles.card}>
              <Text>{this.state.day}</Text>
              </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
             }
}
```

If I click on the card the text value is supposed to change but nothing happens. Also is there a way to change the state automatically when the page loads without having to click on the card? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: should be `setState` instead of `SetState`

Comment: @Cherniv my bad, sorry. Thanks for pointing that out. I changed it but still my variable stays the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onPress code: `<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getSchedules}>`

It should be   `<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getSchedules.bind(this)}>`

By only passing function reference `this` context isn't passed to getSchedules.

Comment: binding in onPress is not good. read this article https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the fetch is working?

I tried your code with a Facebook example url and I got

> Network Request Failed

in the console (`CMD + D` - Debug)

Followed the directions in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38555536/457407) to add the domain to an exception list in `info.plist` and it worked :)

the `info.plist` file is in Xcode and you can update it easier by right clicking and choose "Open as > Source Code" - that way you can copy and paste the code from the above SO answer

Comment: yes, I have done that and yes, it is fetching my data correctly (I have printed it in the console to check if it works and everything's fine)