# Trying to load JSON via url in react-native but not getting correct response

Tags: javascript, php, json, react-native

```
getData() {
return fetch("http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/script.php")
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    response.json();
  })
  .then(responseJson => {
    this.setState({ data: responseJson });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

}

I also tried by putting ?l=1 like " bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/script.php?l=1 ".
The main json file is " bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/feed_data.json ". So i tried "http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/feed_data.json?l=1" this too but nothing changed

What i have to do now to get the json data and use it in my app...Please help

Comment: do you see the console.log ?

Comment: yes ...i checked.

Comment: Response log is here...http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/1.png

Comment: I think your issue lies with the php script. Did you try making the request with Postman? The response comes back as HTML.

Comment: the postman giving me html as response....see here the response of postman bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/postman%20error.png

Answer (score 4):

You are using the arrow function wrong. Instead of this:

```
fetch("http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/script.php")
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    response.json();
  })
  .then(responseJson => {
    this.setState({ data: responseJson });
  })
```

**You should return** the `response.json()`

```
fetch("http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/script.php")
   .then(response => {
     console.log(response);
     return response.json();
   })
   .then(responseJson => {
     this.setState({ data: responseJson });
   })
```

This way you can reach `responseJson` in the next `then`.

Also, if your app complains about `fetch() network request failed` probably it's about Info.plist or Manifest configuration error. See this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed).

For iOS, you can try the same request with this `https` dummy json url:
     https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

Comment: http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/1.png here the response data.
it's not giving the correct data....

Comment: yes i tried with your code then the (screenshot) result appeared.

Comment: http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/feed_data.json?l=1 try with this. Console log both `then` and tell me the outputs.

Comment: http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/up1.png
http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/up2.png
As you told...i did and the outcome is in the screenshots

Comment: check the comment on the question written by @MattyK14

Comment: I  tried via reloading package....nothing happen.
And the postman giving me html as response....see here the response of postman http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/postman%20error.png

Comment: @DebotosDas that's the main reason of failure. You should want your api to return JSON only.

Comment: How do i do that ....will you give me a demo or example link.
I want to add the form (http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd) data in the json file and access that json file from my react-native app....that's all

Answer (score 0):

http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/script.php , this link returns multiple sets of JSON.

([{"FeedTitle":"Debotos","FeedDescription":"First Feed Testing....."},{"FeedTitle":"Akash","FeedDescription":"Creating a clan named \"Khulna Sparkers\""},{"FeedTitle":"Ripon","FeedDescription":"My brother and my one of the closest individual"}])

try this . . .

```
getData() {
 fetch("http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/script.php")
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    response.json();
  })
  .then(responseJson => {
        var length = responseJson.length;
        for (var a = 0; a<length;a++) {
            var FeedTitle = responseJson[a].FeedTitle; //<-variable from your response json
            var FeedDescription = responseJson[a].FeedDescription; //<-from your response json
            console.log(FeedTitle);
            console.log(FeedDescription);
        }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Response log is here http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/1.png
other url (for script.php) is responding the same thing like that one

Comment: take a look at this line {"FeedTitle":"Akash","FeedDescription":"Creating a clan named \"Khulna Sparkers\""} i guess you have a wrong format of Json. json data must be like this {"var":"value"}

Comment: but at offline(via directory path) when i am trying to load that json file it works perfectly....so the json format may be not wrong, it's an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

try axios

```html
npm install --save axios
```

```html
state = {data:[]};
    componentWillMount() {
                 axios.get('http://bitcfeedcms.rf.gd/script.php')
                 .then(response =>this.setState({data:response.data}));
    }
```