# React Native Image Upload via aws Amplify using Storage class

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, blob, aws-amplify

I have an image. I want to upload it to S3 using aws-amplify. All the Storage class upload examples are using text documents; however, I would like to upload an image. I am using expo which does not have support from react-native-fetch-blob, and react native does not have blob support... yet.

So my options seem to be:

1. Create a node service via lambda.
2. Upload only the base64 info to S3 and not a blob.

`` const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status === 'granted') {
      const image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        quality: 0.5,
        base64: true
      });
      const { base64 } = image;
      Storage.put(`${username}-profileImage.jpeg`, base64);
    } ``

Is this Correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT FOR UPDATED ANSWER WITH RN BLOB SUPPORT VERSION:** I have been able to solve this now that React Native has announced blob support and now we only need the uri.  See the following example:

```
uploadImage = async uri => {
  const response = await fetch(uri);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  const fileName = 'profileImage.jpeg';
  await Storage.put(fileName, blob, {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    level: 'private'
  }).then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

**Old Answer**

For all you get to this. I ended up using https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3 This worked perfectly! But not the preferred solution as I would like to use aws-amplify.

Comment: their documentation is not very helpful to perform such an easy task. Interesting discussion related to this issue also found in here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/576

Comment: @Seuential: can you show me more details about the code. I follow the React Native code from https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#put but no hope

Comment: @LuongTruong Are you getting an error message? This is really all the code relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Sequential: thank you for your quick comment. I create a question on stackoverfow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260500/react-native-upload-video-to-aws-s3-storage-using-aws-amplify. There is an error using the code, hope you can take a look and help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @LuongTruong What version of RN do you have?

Comment: @Sequential: I am using react native 0.57.4

Comment: @Sequential: Did you try with the RN 0.57.4? This issue is still bothering me. Please let me know if you can solve it

Comment: @LuongTrong I wonder 9f this is an issue with latest react/expo code looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add a more complete answer to this question.

The below code allows to pick images from the mobile device library using **ImagePicker** from Expo and store the images in S3 using **Storage** from **AWS** **Amplify**.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native'
import { ImagePicker, Permissions } from 'expo'
import { Icon } from 'native-base'

import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core'
import Storage from '@aws-amplify/storage'
import config from './aws-exports'

Amplify.configure(config)

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
  }

  // permission to access the user's phone library
  askPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
  }

  useLibraryHandler = async () => {
    await this.askPermissionsAsync()
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync(
      {
        allowsEditing: false,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      }
    )

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri })
      this.uploadImage(this.state.image)
    }
  }

  uploadImage = async uri => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const fileName = 'dog77.jpeg';
    await Storage.put(fileName, blob, {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      level: 'public'
    }).then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    let { image } = this.state
    let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window')
    return (
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        <Icon 
          name='md-add-circle'
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={this.useLibraryHandler}
        />
        {image &&
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: width, height: height/2 }} />
        }
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, { includeGreetings: true })

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    fontSize: 45, 
    color: '#4286f4'
  }
});
```

Comment: I use your code. The app is able to login, choose the picture. However, after receive the picture there is a warning "Network request failed". I think it comes from `const response = await fetch(uri);` I am using Expo 31.0.2. The same thing happen in Mr. @Sequential code.

Comment: check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed

Comment: I run your example on Android and the link is "https://static.asiachan.com/Berry.Good.600.42297.jpg". I think it is not the `https` problem. Do you have any suggestion? I am willing to hear from you

Comment: downgrade to expo version 30.0.1. My code does not seem to function properly on expo 31. Also make sure to install "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.13" and "buffer": "^5.2.1" using npm. I am happy to provide my package.json if you provide another communication way.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass file object to .put method

```
Storage.put('test.png', file, { contentType: 'image/png' })
  .then (result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: This does not work because a file object is reliant on Blob, but Blob is not yet supported in React Native, so it errors out unless I'm mistaken.