# react native - Upload video to AWS S3 storage using AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to upload a video to AWS S3 by using AWS Amplify in React native. I am able to upload an image when follow this link:

[aws-amplify Upload image using PUT in Storage](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#put)

I apply the same code to upload a video and success. However, the app crash if the video's size is big.

According to the example, they read and convert the image/video file to `base64` (consume memory a lot and even cause the app crash) then upload everything on the server.

## UPDATE

I found the answer using blob from this link

[React native - Upload image to AWS S3 using blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341597/react-native-image-upload-via-aws-amplify-using-storage-class/49345264?noredirect=1#comment93421710_49345264)

```
uploadImageVersion2 = async () => {

    const response = await fetch("https://static.asiachan.com/Berry.Good.600.42297.jpg");
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const fileName = 'profileImage.jpg';
    await Storage.put(fileName, blob, {
        contentType: 'image/jpg',
        level: 'private'
    }).then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

However, there is an error:

[image: using url as uri]

My questions are: 
1/ Is there any way to avoid convert `base64` before upload the image/video using AWS Amplify 
2/ Is there any other ways to upload image/video in React native to AWS S3 without using Storage in AWS Amplify.

If you know the answer of these two questions, please let me know and show me how.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think S3 is not ment for large files like videos. There are other services in aws that can do what you require.
Maybe this will be helpful: https://aws.amazon.com/what-is-cloud-file-storage/

Comment: @squeekyDave: thank you for recommending me a new service like `Cloud File Storage`. The video is about 50MB only. What I want is uploading the video without convert it to `base64` because it read everything to memory and make the app crash. If you know how, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think this might be the solution for you, have a look at this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html
Apologies for the late reply.

Comment: @squeekyDave: Thank you for the link. After taking a look at it I see there is a REST Api to upload things on S3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html. However, I don't know how to use it, do you know where can I find an example for it? I tried but no hope :(