# https fetch request blocking in android and ios - React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, protocols

I build one mobile app using React Native,

In that i am using one api to fetch data, initially i have one web api in http, for example like this: http://example.com it successfully fetch data in android but not in ios,

I read apple docs then i found apple needs https for production apps,

So i decided and change my web api protocol to **https** like this: https://example.com, after changing my api successfully i got response in web page when i hit that url, but now when i am running my React Native application it tells me **Network Request Failed**

I also change my http to https in my React Native fetch request code. I dont know whats the problem is, Is this React Native issue?

Comment: I believe Apple rescinded the https-only policy. Your problem likely lies with something else.

Comment: Then what about in android? if i use https in android it shows that same error Network Request failed.

Comment: Does the API work when you try it on web/Postman? For iOS, you need to edit info.plist to allow https: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427829/6599478. For Android, did you specify INTERNET permission in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: I create, React native app using "create-react-native-app" so i dont have android and ios folder.

Comment: I am using expo client.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios and see if it works. Did you specify your endpoint url with environment var? Make sure it's actually calling the right url.

Comment: @MohamedSameer Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: https is successfully worked on ios, but not working in android devices which have os versions below 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https is not enough for iOS. Your SSL certificate should be in compliance with TSL 1.2 or major by default.

You can override this behavior setting the minimum supported TSL in the info.plist file as follow:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
     <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Worked on iOS, but not on android.