# handle network request failed in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm facing an issue while using react native fetch api. many times request got failure . I have a high speed connection. but many times it got failed.
that issue is happening In android,ios both.

```
const shoppingApi  = 'myserverlink';

async function Sendshoppinapi(data) {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(shoppingApi, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-type':'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: data
        });
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        return responseJson;
    }
    catch (error) {
          Alert.alert(error.toString())
    }
}

export {Sendshoppinapi};
```

data that I sending server as post request

```
  add_to_wishlist = (item,index) => {
        {
          let data = new FormData();
        data.append('methodName',       'add_to_wishlist');
        data.append('user_id',        global.userid)
        data.append('item_id',        this.props.navigation.state.params.itemid.toString())


        Sendshoppinapi(data).then((responseJson)=>{

          console.warn(responseJson);
          if(responseJson.responseCode == '200'){
            this.setState({fav:false})
            Alert.alert('SHOPPING','Item added to wishlist successfully.',[{text: 'OK',},],{ cancelable: false })

          }
          else{
            this.setState({fav:false})
            Alert.alert('SHOPPING','Item already .',[{text: 'OK',},],{ cancelable: false })
          }
        })}
      }
```

Error that when request got failed
[image: error]

[image: fullscreen]

Comment: what is the error that you are facing

Comment: This isn't a clear question, the reasons could be many.

Comment: Ps. you should use the then() function instead of waiting for promises' finish like that

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay I got network request failure when getting information from server it happen many times .I want to get rid of it and need a stablity for it

Comment: There is nothing very wrong with your code. So the request to the server must fail for other reasons. What does the server return as an error?

Comment: @AndreiOlar "network  request failed"....

Comment: @AndriyKlitsuk can u make a snippet for it so I can understand better

Comment: If it's a 5xx error code, then it's your server.

Comment: Redited the post with images....

Comment: A network error request can fail with multiple status codes. What status code does your request fail with?

Comment: @Tanveerbyn could you provide your api url?

Comment: @AndriyKlitsuk sorry I can't...

Comment: Is it local? Is it an IP? Is it https?

Comment: this is http type.

Comment: how can I recall my api when it got failed coz its in another class

Answer (score 2):

Use then() function with promises. (Requested code snippet)

```js
fetch(shoppingApi, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type':'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: data
})
.then((resp) => {
    return resp.json()
})
.then((resp) => {
  //resp contains your json data
});
```

You also can make your function returns a Promise, and use it with then():

```js
function sendShoppingApi(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(shoppingApi, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-type':'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: data
        })
        .then((resp) => {
            return resp.json();
        })
        .then((resp) => {
            resolve(resp);
            
            /*
              you should also check if data is valid, if something went wrong
              you can reject the promise:
              
              if(!dataOK)
                  reject("error message");
            
            */
        });
    });
}
```

So now you can do something like this:

```
sendShoppingApi(data)
.then((resp) => {
    //do stuff with your data
})
.catch((err) => {
    //handle error
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

could be a duplicate of this: [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)

Comment: He is using `then()`. But not this way. He is handling Promises using the `async-await` syntax which is just syntactic sugar for `then().catch()`

Comment: Maybe `then().catch()` is syntactic sugar for `async-await`. He requested code snippet in OP comments, I provided. The question is badly placed and too generic to provide an answer, BTW using `then().catch()` will bring better code and therefore more ease in debug

Comment: again getting the same error like onUnhadled @ promise.js 43:19 and many other

Answer (score 2):

I've quoted an answer I used for another post - however I have added await.

You can check the status of the call, to determine perhaps why the network call failed. Try using fetch's `ok` to check whether the response was valid, for example:

```
.then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        //throw error
    } else {
       //valid response
    }
})
```

Using await:

```
 let response = await fetch(url)
 if (response.ok) return await response.json()
```

You can also access the response's status like:

```
response.status;
```

or also, statusText such as:

```
response.statusText;
```

checkout the below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/statusText

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status

https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/

Comment: This doesn't explain how to prevent the crash, in cases where the network request fails for reasons that are outside of the client/server's control.

Comment: "Network request fails outside the client server control"? Surely you're talking about an application crash?

Comment: No, why would you think that I mean that? I mean that the network request fails for a reason that is outside of the client/server code's control. Networks are never 100% reliable, and a network request can fail for any number of reasons that are not a bug in the client or server code. Do I really need to list examples? Surely you've had a router reset because of a power failure in your house, or because of something your ISP did? Surely you've experienced intermittent network availability on a mobile network?

Answer (score 0):

For the case when you are running the app on the android device, the API is on a computer and both of them are on the same network I have added some possible things to check. I haven't detailed specific solutions since there are many answers on each topic.

- Do a quick check with ngrok https://ngrok.com/ on the free plan to see if that works. If yes:

  - Make sure the API is accessible by trying to access it on the device browser (most important is to check if you allow the port at inbound rules, firewall).
  - If you are using HTTPS, you might get an error if your react native env is not properly configured to accept not trusted certificates, assuming you are using a non trusted one. Do a check without HTTPS, only with HTTP, to see if it's the case. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20488