# React Native Fetch give error "Network request failed"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have the following code for creating an event with a image and some body params. It was working fine when i was doing it without image, i am using `react-native-image-crop-picker` for selecting images. I am getting "Network request failed" error when posting data from react-native. The request never reach my backend as i am getting no logs there. It is working fine with postmen.

MY CODE:

```
const { name, date, description, location, uri, mime, time } = this.state;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', name)
    formData.append('date', date)
    formData.append('description', description)
    formData.append('location', location)
    formData.append('time', time)

    formData.append('image',{
      uri:uri,
      mime:'image/jpeg',
      name:`image${moment()}`
    })


    alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
    const config = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
          body: formData,
      };

    fetch(`http://${Config.apihost}:${Config.port}/events`,config).then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: false, name:'', date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'), description:'', Location: 'AlHedaya Masjid' })
        this.props.addEvent(res.message);

      // this.props.navigation.goBack();
      }).catch((err) => alert(err));
```

I have another screen which contains different number of pictures like gallery i am uploading multiple picture to the gallery, the request is working fine with code below.

```
 const data = new FormData();
        data.append('name', 'avatar');
        images.map((res, i) => {
          data.append('fileData[]', {
            uri: res.path,
            type: res.mime,
            name: `image${i}${moment()}`
          });
        })
        const config = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
          body: data,
        };
        fetch(`http://${Config.apihost}:${Config.port}/events/${this.state.item.id}/photos`, config)
          .then((checkStatusAndGetJSONResponse) => checkStatusAndGetJSONResponse.json())
          .then((response) => {

            if (response.status && response.message.length > 0) {
              var images = this.state.images;
              response.message.map(file => {
                images.push(`http:${Config.apihost}:${Config.port}/images/${file.id}`);
              });
              this.setState({ images });
            }
          }).catch((err) => { alert(err) });
```

I can't really see the difference between the two codes but the upper code giving me error.

- I am testing on android
- I am using the IP address instead of localhost (my others requests are working so thats out of equation)
- None of the solution in this link worked
  [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Should `images.push("http:${Config.apihost}:${Config.port}/images/${file.id}");` be `images.push("http://${Config.apihost}:${Config.port}/images/${file.id}");` ?

Comment: Thats when i actually post successfully to my server .. i am not even getting to my server the request is being stuck somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Nice pick btw but the below code is working fine .. and now i am even more confused that why it is working.

Comment: Yep - just a comment as I was looking at your code as it might be a problem later on

Comment: Are you using Android emulator or real device for testing ?

Comment: I am testing on android emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first code snippet you have written **mime** instead of **type**.

```
formData.append('image',{
      uri:uri,
      **mime:'image/jpeg**',
      name:`image${moment()}`
    })
```

it should be like below snippet

```
formData.append('image',{
          uri:uri,
          type:'image/jpeg',
          name:`image${moment()}`
        })
```

Comment: how did i miss that !!