# how to handle network request failed error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

**my problem differs from [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed), I'm not struggling with http or https, I just want to provide a nice error to the user if the request fails due to the internet connection, wrong API, etc. instead of getting react native error.**

I have a form and want to send it to a server and get a response so I wrote this:

```
submitForm = async () => {
  fetch("www.somewhere.com", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(some_data)
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
     // do something
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({server_error: "request failed try again."});
  });
};
```

But It seems that my catch doesn't work correctly because if the request fails I get an error from react native like this:
[image]
and in production, it just jumps out of the app, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this will solve your problem, but your fetch code tries to create JSON, even if the response is a 404, for example.

You also need to check if the response is OK before creating JSON

```
submitForm = async () => {
  fetch("www.somewhere.com", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(some_data)
  })
  .then((response) => {
        if(response.statusText == "OK" && response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            return response.json()
        } else {
            throw new Error("Server can't be reached!")
        }
    })
  .then((json) => {
     console.log("hooray! we have json!")
     console.log(json)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error fetching data")
      console.log(error)
      console.log(error.message) // Server can't be reached!
      this.setState({server_error: "request failed try again."});
  });
};
```

Comment: So a fetch().catch() is essentially "I could not complete this request" but doesn't provide information beyond that?  Because my thinking was it could still catch if response.json() failed.

Comment: Yes, you can log the error, `catch(error => console.log(error.message))`. But catch only catches actual errors, for example if the internet is down or the url does not exist. A `404` is not considered an error because the server still returns information. BUT you can throw your own error if you get a `404`! I will edit the answer!