# React-Native: TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a problem when I'm doing a SignUp in my Android Application.

```
static creaUtente(identity, FirstName, LastName, FiscalCode , Email) {
        let formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('Identity', identity);
        formdata.append('FirstName', FirstName);
        formdata.append('LastName', LastName);
        formdata.append('FiscalCode', FiscalCode);
        formdata.append('Email', Email);

        console.log(Configuration.base_url.rest + Configuration.apiRoutes.signUp)
        console.log(formdata)

        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            fetch(Configuration.base_url.rest + Configuration.apiRoutes.signUp,{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
                body: formdata
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                if(responseData.Error){
                    Alert.alert("Errore");
                }
                global.utente = responseData;
                resolve(responseData)
            })
            .catch((err) => {reject(err)})
        })
    }
```

This the code that I Use, In the **fetch** I passed a link to my API (That works correctly. It is a https link )

But when I try to signup in my app I receive this error:

Look for example it is the log that i Receive

> [ [ 'Identity',
>        { ProjectName: { Username: 'TNNFRZ77H01G273V', Password: '12345' } } ],
>        [ 'FirstName', 'Fabrizio' ],
>         [ 'LastName', 'Tonno' ],
>        [ 'FiscalCode', 'TNNFRZ77H01G273V' ],    [ 'Email', 'Fabrizio.tonno@email.com' ] ] }  { [TypeError: Network request
>   failed]

I don't know what I can do :( 
Can you help me?

Using the debbuger with Chrome:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (whatwg-fetch.js:504)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:366)
at MessageQueue.js:106
at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
```

package.json

```
    dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.4.2",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "pouchdb-adapter-asyncstorage": "^6.4.1",
    "pouchdb-authentication": "^1.1.3",
    "pouchdb-find": "^7.0.0",
    "pouchdb-react-native": "^6.4.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.4",
    "react-native-ble-manager": "^6.6.2",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-json-tree": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Information you've provided is insufficient. What is the request and response for signup. Check your web console.

Comment: @Bhagirath I don't have a response, because I have this kind of error. My log give me this (I update my post)

Comment: Are you receiving the request logs/access logs on your server for the respective requests? If not try the solution suggested by
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed

Comment: @Bhagirath Thanks for your reply, in the question that you linked there is nothing about android, they talk about the internet permission but I give this :/

Comment: Have you added internet permissions in the Manifest file?

Comment: @JRK Yes I Have

Comment: I'm assuming the phone has signal or WiFi connection?Have you tested your API with Postman or something similar with exactly the same call?

Comment: @JRK Yes the phone is in Wifi Connection, And if I test the API with CocoaRestClient I can do the signup :/

Comment: Are you connecting to the API via localhost at all? If so, put the IP instead.

Comment: @JRK no i don't use localhost :/

Comment: Are you using an actual device or emulator?

Comment: @JRK I use device, because the emulator is too slow :/ (About 15 minutes to start )

Comment: What version of Android?

Comment: @JKR i have Android 8

Comment: I have tried also on the emulator but the result is equal

Comment: Have you tried that request in a HTTP client program such as Postman or Insomnia with the same parameters? @Jack23

Comment: @firats - "I'm assuming the phone has signal or WiFi connection?Have you tested your API with Postman or something similar with exactly the same call?"

Comment: So, problem should be parameters then. @JRK Please try with static variables in your app.

Comment: @firats - this is not my app dude - please comment in the OP.

Comment: I know.. the first sentence was for you. @JRK I just can't tag two of you in the same comment ;)

Comment: @firats I don't think that the problem is the parameters because I take the right parameters.