# Network error axios trying to get data from API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, axios

I'm so tired to fix this problem i'ts work from **https** and it's do not work in **http** please help me

when i am using this api => https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
i'ts work but when i use my api it doesn't work then

here is my code

```
import axios from 'axios'

let baseURL = ''

{
  Platform.OS == 'android'
  ? baseURL = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/' // android
  : baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/' // IOS
}

axios.get(`${baseURL}products`)
.then(res => {console.log(res) })
.catch(err => console.log(err)})
```

i'ts has error

Network Error
at http://packager.x5-xy3.anonymous.g-bazar.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:189790:25 in createError
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:91:24 in handleTimeout
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Comment: It seems like your backend block the request, you need to set the header of the response in the backend, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45975479/12684175)

Comment: you need to allow http requests for iOS. Otherwise you can't access http requests

Comment: @MortadhaFadhlaoui my link is okay but it has error if you know another way please help me

Comment: @Coder where I allow the http request for IOS, why I can't use http ?

Comment: @Coder is right, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49374981/12684175)

Comment: now i have https it's doesn't work yet do you have anther way ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS sdk enforces connection to be in https protocol instead of http.you can add an exception to your domain inside info.plist file of the Xcode project.

Open your info.plist file of your project with any editor of your preference, then add this code at the end of the file before the last

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629980/7578825)

Comment: do you have another way to fix it ?