# React Native Dynamic host name fetch not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native. I'm using fetch to get data from server. in this request url host name is dynamic. when i use it's not working. i tried lots of things none of them is working. here is my code.

```
registerCall = host => {
    var url = 'http://' + host + '/DashboardApi/public/SignIn';
    const username = this.state.Usrname;

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: this.state.password,
      }),
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        if (result == false) {
          Alert.alert('Wrong Username or Password!');
        } else {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(result[1]));
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        alert('result:' + error);
      });  
};
```

I'm getting this error

```
error TypeError: Network request failed
    at EventTarget.xhr.onerror (D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:473)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818)
    at EventTarget.setReadyState (D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:575)
    at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:389)
    at D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:502
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425)
    at D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112
    at MessageQueue.__guard (D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (D:\React Native\dashboard_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, 'it's not working'?

Comment: Network request failed error

Comment: Please share the error in full

Comment: i added error image

Comment: When i hard coded the url it's working.

Comment: const username = this.state.Usrname; You sure "Usrname" is the correct spelling?

Comment: Ok. Inside you catch block please type `console.log('error', error)`. Then open the developer menu in react native and select debug. ln chrome or your debugger open dev tools and you will see the full error. Please paste that error in to your question. Also make sure that `host` is not undefined.

Comment: Can you print what value you are getting in username? The complete URL should be like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172776/react-naive-dynamic-host-name-fetch-not-woring

Comment: no error in this.state.Usrname spelling

Comment: @shubham url is getting like this http://192.168.100.56:92/DashboardApi/public/SignIn

Comment: @Mr.Robot  added the error

Comment: What is the value of `host`?

Comment: @Mr.Robot 123.231.114.160:91

Comment: try hitting the complete url by hard coding

Comment: @shubham hard coded url working fine

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
'http://' + host + '/DashboardApi/public/SignIn'
```

use backticks

```
var url = `http://$host/DashboardApi/public/SignIn`
console.log(`dynamic url = $url`)
```

then compare the url what you have hardcoded with the dynamic url. It's very simple

Comment: I tried it but not working!
added like this ```   
  var url = `http://${host}/DashboardApi/public/SignIn`; 
  ```

Comment: @Thanushka I can't comment so I answered. You must check whether your server takes only signed url or not. In my company we design servers to accept only signed url. Check it

Comment: @Thanushka also try with `https`

Comment: I tried with RestMan extention response getting correctly and when hard coded url it's working. it's not working when host name getting dynamic.

Comment: @Thanushka are you sure the harcoded and dynamic values are same. did you consoled it and cross checked properly.

Comment: @Thanushka also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427829/14016776

Comment: yes i checked it. i'm getting the host name from state. can that be a problem?

Comment: @Thanushka back ticks will convert anything into string. So you must only see wheather you are getting proper text value from state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218899/discussion-between-thanushka-and-rock).