# React Native returns [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed] while requesting node.js api on localhost

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using my android device to run the application.

I am importing 'react-native-axios' for this.

I tried using 10.0.2.2, 192.168.1.77 both. Nothing works for me.

```
const data = {
   firstname: "abc",
   lastname: "xyz"
   email: "abc@gmail.com",
   password:"123456"
}
axios.post(`http://192.168.1.77:3000/signup`, data)
.then(response=>{
  console.log(response)
})
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err)
})
```

I am getting the following while making the Axios request.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
    * http://packager.zv-7nw.dhruvil18.frontend.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:26416:19 in <unknown>   
    * http://packager.zv-7nw.dhruvil18.frontend.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:31004:20 in <unknown>   
    * http://packager.zv-7nw.dhruvil18.frontend.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:30920:8 in _callTimer   
    * http://packager.zv-7nw.dhruvil18.frontend.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:31128:8 in Object.callTimers
    * http://packager.zv-7nw.dhruvil18.frontend.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:3149:30 in MessageQueue.__callFunction
    * http://packager.zv-7nw.dhruvil18.frontend.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:2881:16 in <unknown>    
    * http://packager.zv-7nw.dhruvil18.frontend.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:3103:12 in MessageQueue.__guard
    * http://packager.zv-7nw.dhruvil18.frontend.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:2880:13 in MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    * http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639.js:4:901 in <unknown>
```

[Got ip from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E8qw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)

Comment: I tried using both ipv4 and 10.0.2.2. Nothing is working for me.