# TypeError: Network request failed in react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, api

I'm new react native I have node.js project. When I running the node.js project locally and tries to connect with react native through fetch/axios method I got this error.

```
[TypeError: Network request failed]
```

My api calling function is ,

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:4545/User/SignUp'
const getMe = () => {
  fetch(URL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log('>>>>>>>\n\n\n\n',json,'\n\n\n\n<<<<<<<<'))
  .catch((e =>console.log('>>>>>>>\n\n\n\n',e,'\n\n\n\n<<<<<<<<')))
}
```

what's going wrong here
Thanks advance !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)

Comment: when i used the JSON placeholder its working fine . But not working at my localhost