# I am not able to fetch data from json-server running on my localhost:30001 in my expo project from my mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo, json-server

**When I use lacalhost:3001 then it will work fine on web but not able to fetch data on android device even when I changed localhost to my IP address then it also loads for sometime and after that it shows network request fail I am also attaching the code of that component I have used redux thunk to fetch data from my json-server I have used npm json-server [screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRt4O.jpg)
I guess something is wrong with my baseUrl

export const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3001/";
** -

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import { View ,Text, FlatList,ScrollView} from 'react-native';  
 import {Card, ListItem, Avatar} from 'react-native-elements';
 import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      leaders: state.leaders
    }
  }

function History(){
        return(
            <Card>
                <Card.Title>Our History</Card.Title>
                <Card.Divider />
                <Card.FeaturedSubtitle style={{color:"#2B2928"}}>Started in 2010, Ristorante con Fusion quickly established itself as a culinary icon par excellence in Hong Kong. With its unique brand of world fusion cuisine that can be found nowhere else, it enjoys patronage from the A-list clientele in Hong Kong.  Featuring four of the best three-star Michelin chefs in the world, you never know what will arrive on your plate the next time you visit us.</Card.FeaturedSubtitle>
                <Card.FeaturedSubtitle style={{color:"#2B2928"}}>The restaurant traces its humble beginnings to The Frying Pan, a successful chain started by our CEO, Mr. Peter Pan, that featured for the first time the world's best cuisines in a pan.</Card.FeaturedSubtitle>           
            </Card>
        )
}


 class AboutComponent extends Component {




render() {

    const renderLeader = ({item, index}) => {
        return (    
                <ListItem key={index} >
                    <Avatar rounded source={{uri: baseUrl + item.image}} />
                    <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
                    <ListItem.Subtitle>{item.description}</ListItem.Subtitle>
                    </ListItem.Content>                      
                </ListItem>
        );
    };

   
    if (this.props.leaders.isLoading) {
        return(
            <ScrollView>
                <History />
                <Card
                    title='Corporate Leadership'>
                    <Loading />
                </Card>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
    else if (this.props.leaders.errMess) {
        return(
            <ScrollView>
                <History />
                <Card
                    title='Corporate Leadership'>
                    <Text>{this.props.leaders.errMess}</Text>
                </Card>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
    else{
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <History/>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Title>Corporate Leadership</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Divider />
                    <FlatList 
                        data={this.props.leaders.leaders}
                        renderItem={renderLeader}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}  
                    />                                  
                </Card>               
            </ScrollView>           
        )
    }

}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AboutComponent);
```

Comment: You can't use localhost because localhost vary between clients. localhost of your emulator or device means localhost of that device. However if you are in the same network with your server, you can give the local network ip of your server. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689093/5793132

Comment: Yes,I have used json-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 ./db.json --watch command and Now it's working