# React Native Axios request on iOS returns "Network Error"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, networking, https, axios

I created a RN project (without Expo) and setup my API services. I'm using [dummyapi.io](https://dummyapi.io/) to get dummy post data, which is a HTTPS request. I keep getting "Network Error" from Axios and when I look into error details I see the following message:

```
"_response": "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “dummyapi.io” which could put your confidential information at risk."
```

Everything works fine on Android, so I think this is about Apple's insane security rules.

I've tried adding the following on my Info.plist but no use:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.dummyapi.io</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

To further explain my problem, a GET call to "google.com" works, but "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" does not. I would appreciate any help about this issue, I'm pretty desperate at this point.

```
React Native Version: 0.66.4
React Version: 17.0.2
Axios Version: 0.24.0
```

Comment: did you get the solution.
adding 
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
not working for me.

Comment: @AvinashAjayPandey Yes, you can check my own answer below. It was a combination of my answer and changing my network. Secure networks can mess things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT, thanks to this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29908)! Apparently the app needs to be completely up and running before making any API calls, which resulted in something like this in App.js

```
import {AppState} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    {AppState.currentState === 'active' && <Navigation />}
  );
};
```

Hope this helps anyone who comes across a similar problem!

Answer (score 5):

You're right about IOS's security rules. Add the following to `plist.info` disables all App Transport Security restrictions and should allow you to connect via HTTP:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Otherwise, you will have to generate a root CA certificate, install it on your device.

Here's how to generate the root certificate and use it to generate self-signed certificates: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/runbook-automation?topic=certificate-generate-root-ca-key
Here's how to install it on an IOS device: https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/self-signed-certificates-in-ios-apps-ff489bf8b96e

This question is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427829/17922074.

Comment: I did, unfortunately it doesn't work...

Comment: Then you might have to install the certificate on your device. You'll need a root certificate to do this, here's how to generate one: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/runbook-automation?topic=certificate-generate-root-ca-key. This is how to install the root certificate on your device: https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/self-signed-certificates-in-ios-apps-ff489bf8b96e

Comment: Please let me know if it works so I can adapt my answer accordingly for others facing the same issue.

Comment: I'll look into it, but what I don't understand is, when I send my repo to an employer and they run the app on their device or a simulator, wouldn't it cause a similar problem since they won't have the certificate I created?

Comment: This may depend on many things and I'm not an expert but in general I would say yes. If they're using IOS, their OS should block the connection too.

Answer (score 5):

to fix this issue follow this steps :

1- go to `info.plist`.

2- next go to the key

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
```

3- inside the `<dict></dict>` of the key add this code :

```
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Erasing the simulator and creating a new one WORKED! (try with a different simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Open `Info.plist` in your `ios` directory and add this to your file:

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true />
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true />
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```