# React-native - iOS - Cannot fetch data from localhost

Tags: ios, react-native, localhost

i have the problem, that i can not do a fetch request to localhost api.
If a have my business logic on a server, everything works.

I use iOS and react-native 0.68.2.

If i run my app with xCode a get the following error:

```
2022-06-24 19:24:35.088109+0200 MyApp[46047:7055248] Task <409DD042-5979- 
4A48-8781-C1E90F7AC8A4>.<4> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x280e62160 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 " 
(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: lo0, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, 
_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <409DD042-5979-4A48-8781- 
C1E90F7AC8A4>.<4>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
   "LocalDataTask <409DD042-5979-4A48-8781-C1E90F7AC8A4>.<4>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost/MyApp/business/public/api/get-offerings,             
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost/MyApp/business/public/api/get-offerings, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

flipper: Desktop failed to provide certificates. Error from flipper desktop:
rsocket::StreamInterruptedException: connection error
```

I already add the following in my Info.plist, but i get after this an error

```
<key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
<true>
```

Error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed
```

Can someone help me why i cant do a request to localhost? I use XAMPP and the server is running. If i use PostMan to Test my request, everything works with the given Error (URL is included in the error). Should i use a IP? If i fetch to a server, everything works with Postman and request in the app. If i use instance of "localhost", "127.0.0.1" i also get the error "network request failed"

Answer (score 1):

Open your Xcode project and under info tab add these settings..

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        
    </dict>
</dict>
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem was not to use "localhost". I used my IP from the network and it works.

I got my solution from this post [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)