# How do I resolve the Axios Network Error I am receiving when pulling data from my Express backend API?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, axios

I am trying to combine my react native and database together by using following code:

```
const axiosInstance=axios.create({
    baseURL: config.API_URL
 })
try{
    const res =  await axiosInstance.get("/all")
    console.log("res",res)
    return res.data
    }catch(err){
        console.log("error:",err)
    }
    await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/all').then(abc=>console.log(abc.data)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

My API link is: http://localhost:5000/all
It should get me the json within the api but it just outputs error :

error: [AxiosError: Network Error]

I have used cors and my backend is:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors((req,callback)=>{
    callback(null,{
        origin:true
    })
}))
app.use('/',router)
```

inside router:

```
const getAllUser=async(req,res)=>{
    const data =await userSchema.find()
    return res.json(data)
}
router.get('/all',getAllUser);
```

I cant seem to figure out where the problem is occouring from.

I tried using cors as cors() it didnt work .
I have tried both axiosInstance and normal axios method.

Comment: is your app listening on port 5000 ? since this is a GET request, you should be able to open your browser, go to http://localhost:5000/all and get a response. Is it the case ?

Comment: yes localhost:5000/all gives response currently i deleted all data manually from atlas so its showing [ ]

Comment: So this problem occurs only if you have some document in the collection?

Comment: no it occours everytime no matter the state of data in table

Answer (score 0):

Since your api is not the problem and you mentioned using react native, maybe your question is related to this other SO question
[React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)