# TypeError: Network request failed with react native flask API

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-native, flask

I am getting the warning when trying to use the code below in react native:

```
"WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Network request failed
TypeError: Network request failed"
at anonymous (http://MYIPADDRESS:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:5158:33)
    at apply (native)
    at anonymous (http://MYIPADDRESS:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:29724:26)
    at _callTimer (http:/MYIPADDRESS:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:29663:17)
    at callTimers (http://MYIPADDRESS:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:29819:19)
    at apply (native)
    at __callFunction (http://MYIPADDRESS:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2826:36)
    at anonymous (http://MYIPADDRESS:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2587:31)
    at __guard (http://MYIPADDRESS:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2777:15)
    at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://MYIPADDRESS:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2586:21)
```

I tried doing the stuff mentioned here -> [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)
But none seemed to work. I checked the info.plist file, and the 'NSAppTransportSecurity' is set to true for everything, including http. I have added "private": true, "proxy": "http://localhost:3000" to my package.json file. I usually run the iOS simulator, but I tried to run the android and web simulator and they didn't work either.

My code for react:

```js
const [data, setdata] = useState({
    quote: "",
   // author: "",
    //date: ""
});

// Using useEffect for single rendering
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Calling effect......")
    // Using fetch to fetch the api from
    // flask server it will be redirected to proxy
    fetch("/get-quote/1")
    .then(function(res){
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        // Setting a data from api
        setdata({
        name: data.quote_text,
                //author: data.speaker_name,
                //date: data.year_of_quip,
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
    // ADD THIS THROW error
    throw error;
    })
})
```

Here is my server.py that I am running:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import select, func, text
import datetime


app = Flask(__name__)

#app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost:3306/Quippy_v01"


@app.route('/get-quote/<quip_location>', methods=["GET"])
def returnQuoteBasedOnLocation(quip_location):


    currentDate = datetime.datetime.now()

    currentDate = currentDate.date()

    print("Current Date: {0}".format(currentDate))


    dailyQuote = "fetch this string!"

    #Iterate through cursor to get data

    dailyQuoteDict ={
        "quote_text" : dailyQuote,
    }

    #Jsonify and return data for Frontend.
    #NOTE: 200 is the HTTP code for 'Success.'
    return jsonify(dailyQuoteDict), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", debug = True, port="3000")
```

Thanks in advance for any help.