# React Native won't connect to API but React and browser can

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, fetch-api

I'm using React Native Expo with Android, React, and Express for the API.

When I visit the API's address I get a message. When I fetch it from React I get a message. When I try to fetch from React Native I get "Error fetching data: [TypeError: Network request failed]" in my console and nothing in the JS debugger.

I've tried multiple ports for all sources and axios. I've altered cors for specific ports, restarted everything multiple times, checked permissions.

Here are the test apps I made - I get the same results every time. Thanks!

Express

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors'); // Import the cors middleware
const app = express();
const port = 4321;

// Use the cors middleware
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({message: 'Hello'});
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

React Native

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4321');
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Data from the server:', data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <></>
  );
};

export default App;
```

React (same as RN)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4321');
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Data from the server:', data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <></>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native fetch() Network Request Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed)