# Prevent React Native from changing POST to GET request

Tags: android, post, get, react-native

For some reason when sending off requests from an actual android device using React Native as a POST the server only receives GET requests.  Can someone explain why this is happening and how to prevent the protocol switching? I read somewhere that specifying the HEADERS will help fix this but not true. Have any others also experienced this anomaly?

```
addTask = async (title, imgFile) => {

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("json", JSON.stringify({ title: title, status: "New", priority: "Normal" }));
axios.request({
  url: API_URL + 'tasks',
  method: 'post',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(response => {
  console.log('response', response);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for POST requests https is required rather than http...
I found the result from [StackOverflow - 34570193](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570193/react-native-post-request-via-fetch-throws-network-request-failed)

I don't recall experiencing any Networking Errors this is why I never looked over this posting in the first place. Hope this helps somebody.