# React Native Fetch() with FormData() HTTP TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Am using **FormData()** and **Fetch()** to Post and Image File to My Server After Tacking A picture on Android.

*am using a public IP not posting to my localhost or anything and not using HTTPS, also using Genymotion Emulator.*

**My Code :**

```
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('image', {path:'file:///'}); 

      fetch(UPLOAD_URI,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: fd
        }).then(response => {
          console.log("image uploaded")
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
```

**Error Returned In the catch as the param err:**

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.js:441)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:542)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:378)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:482
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:236)
    at MessageQueue.js:108
    at guard (MessageQueue.js:46)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:107)
```

Is there some kind of permissions that am missing , whats the problem ?

Cheers,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Post Request via Fetch throws Network Request Failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570193/react-native-post-request-via-fetch-throws-network-request-failed)

Comment: that one is with HTTPS , and not using HTTPS

Comment: Your uri is https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my case on android the following module helped me to solve this issue as it was using java to send my file to the server and to be fetched using $_FILES in PHP :

```
npm install react-native-file-transfer-android
```

**My Code :**

```
var FileTransfer = require('react-native-file-transfer-android');

const UPLOAD_URI = "http://< IP / Domain>/index.php"


  makeUuid()
  {
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

      for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
          text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

      return text;
  }

  sendImageToServer(data){

        var uuid = this.makeUuid();
        FileTransfer.upload({
          uri: data,
          uploadUrl: UPLOAD_URI,
          fileName: 'temp.jpg',
          mimeType: 'image/jpg',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
          data: {
            name:uuid
          }
            }, (err, res) => {
              if(err) {
                console.error(err);
              } else {
                console.log(res);
              }
          });
   }

  saveImage(imgDate){

    let states = {camera:false};
    states[this.state.ActiveImage] = imgDate.path;
    this.sendImageToServer(imgDate.path);
    this.setState({
      ...states
    });




  }
```

Cheers.